# Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Delete_rows event on table Replication error?

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

I am in the process of migrating an on prem mysql database to amazon aurora and used the [official AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Migrating.ExtMySQL.html). Per the Docs these are the steps that i have followed so far:-

1. Set up Percona Xtrabackup.
2. Took a backup and moved the data to S3.
3. Went to RDS Dashboard and restored the database from S3.
4. The Database is up and running successfully.

Now i am in the process of setting up **binlog** replication where my Aurora instance will be the replica while my on prem mysql is the master. To set up replication, i followed the steps as laid down in the official docs:-

1. On my master, created a user 'replica-aurora' and provided the necessary permissions using `GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replica-aurora'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-secret-password';`
2. Ran Show master status on my master which in on prem.

   ```
    File: mysql-bin.004762
     Position: 68093017
     Binlog_Do_DB: 
     Binlog_Ignore_DB: 
     Executed_Gtid_Set: 
     1 row in set (0.00 sec)
   ```
3. Connected to my aurora instance and ran the following command :-

   ```
   CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master ('Ip-of-master', 3306, 'replica-aurora',  'password', 'mysql-bin.004762', 68093017, 0);
   ```
4. Ran `CALL mysql.rds_start_replication;`
5. When i check the `show slave Status\G`. I keep running into the following error message :-

   ```
   Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                 Master_Host: Master-IP
                 Master_User: replica-aurora
                 Master_Port: 3306
               Connect_Retry: 60
             Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.004762
         Read_Master_Log_Pos: 71341857
              Relay_Log_File: relaylog.000002
               Relay_Log_Pos: 195715
       Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.004762
            Slave_IO_Running: Yes
           Slave_SQL_Running: No
             Replicate_Do_DB: 
         Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
          Replicate_Do_Table: 
      Replicate_Ignore_Table: mysql.rds_replication_status,mysql.rds_monitor,mysql.rds_sysinfo,mysql.rds_configuration,mysql.rds_history
     Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
     Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                  Last_Errno: 1032
                  Last_Error: Could not execute Delete_rows event on table db.feed; Can't find record in 'feed', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin.004762, end_log_pos 68293560
                Skip_Counter: 0
         Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 68288412
             Relay_Log_Space: 3249360
             Until_Condition: None
              Until_Log_File: 
               Until_Log_Pos: 0
          Master_SSL_Allowed: No
          Master_SSL_CA_File: 
          Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
             Master_SSL_Cert: 
           Master_SSL_Cipher: 
              Master_SSL_Key: 
       Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
       Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
               Last_IO_Errno: 0
               Last_IO_Error: 
              Last_SQL_Errno: 1032
              Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Delete_rows event on table db.feed; Can't find record in 'feed', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin.004762, end_log_pos 68293560
   ```

I tried setting sql_slave_skip_counter=1 and ran into this :-

`mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_slave_skip_counter = 1; ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`

I tried skipping the current position using `CALL mysql.rds_skip_repl_error;` but ran into the following :-

```
mysql> CALL mysql.rds_skip_repl_error;
+-------------------------------------+
| Message                             |
+-------------------------------------+
| Statement in error has been skipped |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Message                                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Slave has encountered a new error. Please use SHOW SLAVE STATUS to see the error. |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (2.14 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (2.14 sec)
```

which is essentially the same error message as posted above. ERROR 1032.

Any one has ideas on how to fix this problem? I sure would appreciate that.

Comment: Did you lock the master when `Took a backup and moved the data to S3.` ? You run show master status after you are done with the backup and I think it is wrong   because master has changed  position.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Thank you for replying. I did not lock the master. Since it's production. You think i should be using the master position when the backup was taken?

Comment: To get a clean replication you should: `flush tables with read lock;` then `show master status;`  Copy and save the data you will need File and Position. Then run the mysqldump command and after the command has finished you can unlock tables `unlock tables;`

Comment: Thanks @ErgestBasha i'll try that.